# grub menu does not show windows 8 option after installing kubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

I recently installed kubuntu 14.04 on my machine that had windows 8.1 pre-installed.However, after restarting the system the grub menu does not show windows 8 option.

I've already tried updating the grub by using  `sudo update-grub2` but nothing happens.

I've also tried the boot-repair option and I got this URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9693911

Now,How do I proceed to get the windows 8 option on the grub menu ?

Edit:

I also tried putting a windows 8 entry in the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file:

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

and after selecting the Windows 8 option I get an error:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /*************some path type structure********************/
error: cannot load image
```